# graphael charts with dynamic data from database using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, graphael

I would like to understand how to get data from a database and show that data inside a graphael chart. 
I'm working in ASP.NET MVC3 and I really don't understand how to make the things working.
 
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great I solved the problem!
I think that could be useful for someone else too:

here it is the Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult ActionName()
        {
            List<String> data = new List<String>();
            data.Add("legend0_4");
            data.Add("legend1_5");
            data.Add("legend2_8");
            data.Add("legend3_12");
            data.Add("legend4_8");

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

here it is the ajax side that also creates the pie chart:

jQuery.getJSON("/ControllerName/ActionName", function (data) {

```
// # Init
var levels = [], values = [];


for (var id in data) {
    var compo = data[id].split("_");
    levels.push("%%.%% " + compo[0]);
    values.push(parseInt(compo[1]));
}

var r = Raphael("accountCharts"),
            pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, values, { legend: levels, legendpos: "west", href: ["http://raphaeljs.com", "http://g.raphaeljs.com"] });

r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
pie.hover(function () {
    this.sector.stop();
    this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);

    if (this.label) {
        this.label[0].stop();
        this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
    }
}, function () {
    this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");

    if (this.label) {
        this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "bounce");
        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
    }
});
```

});